# What if someone posts a translated answer of another Answer?

Tags: discussion, flags

For example, if an answer takes an existing brainfuck answer and rewrites it in another language like [Ook!](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ook!) which is the same underlying language with different symbols.\$^1\$

What I should do if there is a translated Copy answer, Should I flag?

<sub>1</sub> <sub>Only Language derivatives</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you think it is low-effort and low-quality, downvote it. That's what downvotes are for.

We allow duplicate answers on CGCC even in the same language with identical code, so this isn't against our rules.